# fetching / Select data from sql server 2008 into data gridview

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone help me for database query to display data fetched / selected from Sql Server 2008 into c# Desktop application. I have attached required table diagram & also data grid view please answer as soon as possible. I need to display in gridview is:

1. Godown id
2. Godown Name
3. Type Name
4. Count Name
5. Bags
6. lbs per bag
7. total lbs

diagrams:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer:

```
select 
    g.godown_id, g.godown_name, t.type_name, b.count, r.bags_received,
    b.lb_per_bag, s.supplier_name
from
    tbl_yarn_book b, tbl_godown g, tbl_godown_transaction gt, 
    tbl_yarn_receive r, tbl_yarn_supplier s, tbl_yarn_type t                        
where
    gt.godown_id = g.godown_id 
    and gt.receive_id = r.receive_id
    and r.book_id = b.book_id 
    and b.type_id = t.type_id 
    and b.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
```

Comment: See: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)